# Let $s_k(n)$ denote number of digits in $(k+2)^n$ in base $k$ , evaluate $\lim_{n→∞}\frac{s_6(n)s_4(n)}{n^2}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Let $s_k(n)$ denote number of digits in $(k+2)^n$  in base $k$ , evaluate $\lim_{n→∞}\frac{s_6(n)s_4(n)}{n^2}$.

How to find out the number of digits in a particular base? Any hint for the problem is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s a bit to get you started. An integer $n$ requires $d$ digits in base $k$ if $k^{d-1}\le n<k^d$, i.e., if $d-1\le\log_kn<d$. Thus, the number of base $k$ digits in $n$ is $\lfloor\log_kn\rfloor+1$. In particular, the number of digits in $(k+2)^n$ in base $k$ is

$$\lfloor\log_k(k+2)^n\rfloor+1=\lfloor n\log_k(k+2)\rfloor+1\;,$$

so

$$s_6(n)s_4(n)=(\lfloor n\log_68\rfloor+1)(\lfloor n\log_46\rfloor+1)$$